# How does the Salesforce Data "Entry Criteria" work in Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I would like to create a Journey which initiates when a Contact record **Is Created** and **Is Updated** (meets specific criteria).

What I want to know is when **Is Updated** is used in conjunction with the **Meets Specific Event Criteria** does this trigger when the fields updated meet the specific criteria OR if any updates occur and the record meets the criteria?

Example Event Criteria
If my event criteria was Contact.EmailOptOut = TRUE.

Scenario 1:
Contact record updated, Contact.EmailOptOut goes from FALSE to TRUE.

Scenario 2:
Contact record gets updated, Contact.Email has been CHANGED and Contact.EmailOptOut ALREADY set to TRUE (so technically no change).

Can someone explain which scenario will play out with the event criteria set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only scenario 1 will launch the entry. The whole thing is built to only react to changes that set a record to the exact criteria defined in the entry event. If the record already met the criteria before the update (other fields with no criteria relevance) nothing will happen.

**Important Note:** Filter criteria in related records (eg Account properties for a Contact) are not evaluated for the event trigger described above. Those are only used as "secondary" qualifiers once a record is evaluated because it met the trigger criteria. That is the reason why you define those in a separate step of the entry event.